# C library to connect to MS SQL server [for iOS]

Tags: objective-c, c, database, ios4, database-connection

Is there any library in C which can be used to connect to **MS SQL Server** and that can also be used within iOS as C is the subset of Obj-C.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to connect Microsoft SQL server in iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993516/how-to-connect-microsoft-sql-server-in-iphone)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, googling says http://www.mobilefoo.com/ProductDetail.aspx/iSql This one uses a .NET web-to-sql proxy on server side.

Answer (score 2):

yes there is an open source C library called [FreeTDS](http://www.freetds.org). I created this [Objective-C wrapper](https://github.com/martinrybak/SQLClient) for it. Hope it's what you need!